# Apply advanced filter when report's headers come on different rows

Tags: excel, vba

I want to apply Advanced filters to reports, the headers of which can be on row 24, on other reports on row 27, and so on.

Is there a way to adapt the code to identify which is the row on which the headers are?

I also want to adapt the code to apply the filters to different columns. On some reports the columns to filter are AT and AU, on others they are BK and BL.

```
Sub GetUniqueList()

'   Defines variable
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook
        Sheets(1).Activate
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        LastRow = .Range("BK" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    MsgBox ("The last row of data is: " & LastRow)

'   Gets the unique list of recommendations and copies it on column BA
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Range("BK27:BL" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("BY27"), Unique:=True
    End With

'   Goes to Unique table
    ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    Range("BY27").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get header row**

Assume this to be your main issue:

> *"Is there a way to adapt the code to identify which is the row on which the headers are?"*

**Method**

1. Define a `header` string (names separated by colons, eg. `"Col1,Col2,Col3"`) as a first argument and
2. call a function with the sheet's CodeName, e.g. `Sheet1` (*alternatively* `ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet1")`) as second argument:

   GetHeaderRow(header, Sheet1)

**Example call**

```
Option Explicit

Sub IdentifyHeaderRow()
Dim header As String
header = "Col1,Col2,Col3"

Dim startRow As Long
startRow = GetHeaderRow(header, Sheet1)
Debug.Print startRow
'...
End Sub
```

```
Function GetHeaderRow(header As String, sht As Worksheet, _
                      Optional maxRows As Long = 27, _
                      Optional delim As String = ",") As Long
' Purpose: find header row in given worksheet (search up to 27 rows by default)
' Note:    header argument includes colons as delimiter by default
Dim possibleHeaders
possibleHeaders = sht.Range("A1").Resize(maxRows, UBound(Split(header, ",")) + 1).Value
Dim i As Long, currHeader As String
For i = 1 To UBound(possibleHeaders)
    currHeader = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(possibleHeaders, i, 0))), ",")
    If LCase(currHeader) = LCase(header) Then Exit For
Next i
GetHeaderRow = IIf(i <= UBound(possibleHeaders), i, Cells.Rows.Count)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi T.M., thank you so much. A few minutes ago I came up with an idea - to add a variable for the type of report, and make VBA select a different procedure for each according to what report I choose. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your code so that it is a little bit more flexible regarding rows and columns

```
Sub TestIt()
    GetUniqueList ActiveSheet, 27, "BK", ActiveSheet.Range("BY27")
    ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("BY27").Select


    GetUniqueList ActiveSheet, 24, "AT", ActiveSheet.Range("AW24")
    ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("AW24").Select

End Sub

Sub GetUniqueList(ws As Worksheet, startRow As Long, colLetter As String, rgCopyTo As Range)


    Dim colNumber As Long
    colNumber = ws.Range(colLetter & 1).Column

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'MsgBox ("The last row of data is: " & LastRow)

    Dim rgData As Range
    With ws
        Set rgData = Range(.Cells(startRow, colNumber), .Cells(LastRow, colNumber + 1))
    End With

    '   Gets the unique list of recommendations and copies it  to rgCopyTo
    rgData.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rgCopyTo, Unique:=True

End Sub
```

The other question *Is there a way to adapt the code to identify which is the row on which the headers are, independently of the type of report?* is IMHO too general without having further information, at least for me.

Comment: Thank you, Storax, Looking at your suggested code, I just came up with an idea - add a variable where I can ask for the type of report, and select a different procedure for each. Thanks again!